# Transformar form html com lista em json com jQuery ou js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

Eu quero chegar no seguinte json para enviar a minha API.

```
{
    "Ticket":"123456",
    "toDoList": 
    [{
        "Server":"123",
        "UserName":"asd",
        "Password":"asd",
        "File":""
    },
    {
        "Server":"123",
        "UserName":"asd",
        "Password":"asd",
        "File":""
    }]
}
```

Pra isso criei o seguinte html:

```
<form id="guide" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">

                <h1>Welcome!</h1>

                <div id="info">
                    <input name="Ticket" type="text" placeholder="Ticket" id="ticket"/>
                </div>

                <h2>Scripts</h2>

                <div id="toDoList">

                    <div id="todo">
                        <input name="Server" type="text" placeholder="Servidor" id="server" />
                        <input name="User" type="text" placeholder="Usuário" />
                        <input name="Password" type="text" placeholder="Senha" />
                        <br/>
                        <input name="file" type="file" id="fUpload" />
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div id="addToDoButton">
                    <button id="createToDo"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle fa-3x"></i></button>
                </div>

                <div id="sendButton">
                    <input type="submit" id="btnSend" value="Enviar Roteiro" />
                </div>

            </form>
```

Ai vem um código maroto pra inserir novas divs(#todo):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var divPai = $('#toDoList');
    var btnCriar = $('#createToDo');


    btnCriar.click(function () {
        event.preventDefault();
        divPai.append("<div id='todo'><input name='Server' type='text' placeholder='Servidor' /><input name='User' type='text' placeholder='Usuário' /><input name='Password' type='text' placeholder='Senha' /><br/><input name='file' type='file' multiple id='fUpload' /></div>");
    });
```

e nesse momento eu pensei que se usasse um $("#guide").serialize, ele fosse pegar as divs de mesmo nome e inserir em uma lista de toDoList. Acredito que minha esperança foi loge demais. Também tentei usar ul-li para listar os toDo mas, nada vira uma lista.

Tem alguma tag específica para fazer isso?, preciso montar o json na mão? qual a melhor saída senhores.

Já deixo um obrigado pra quem tentar ajudar :D

Comment: Precisas da ID `id="todo"`?

Comment: Não, só quero ter uma lista de ToDo no meu json...